Can Apache Mahout 14.1's lucene.vector utility work with Index built with Apache Lucene 9.5.0?
I am trying to use Apache Mahout to run clustering algorithms on Lucene index data. The index is built with Lucene's version 9.5.0. I have seen that Mahout uses 8.5.0 version of Lucene in it's pom file. So does that mean it will not be able to read my index which is built with Lucene 9.5.0. Is there a plan to upgrade Mahout in near future to support the newer versions of Lucene?
I couldn't get Apache Mahout 14.1's command line version working but with 0.13.0, it shows the following error when running lucene.vector utility -
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooNewException: Format version is not supported (resource BufferedChecksumIndexInput(MMapIndexInput(path="/path/to/myindex"))): 10 (needs to be between 0 and 6)
